# How an operator is converted to a function?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, matrix-elements

$$\langle m|F|n\rangle^*=\langle F(n)|m\rangle$$
How does the operator become a function of state $|n\rangle$?

Comment: For <m|F|n>*=<F(n)|m>

Answer (score 3):

Since $\langle m|F|n\rangle^* = \langle n| F^\dagger |m\rangle$ we can rename the left side into a new bra vector  $\langle F(n)| := \langle n | F^\dagger$. There is really no math or physics happening here, only a renaming of terms.